# Correct way to handle circular reference problem in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, circular-reference

I'm trying to build a simple json parser and below is my JSON type representation with a sealed class

```
sealed interface JValue {
    data class JString(val value: String): JValue
    data class JNumber(val value: Float): JValue
    data class JBool(val value: Boolean): JValue
    data object JNull: JValue
    data class JObject(val value: Map<String, JValue>): JValue
    data class JArray(val value: List<JValue>): JValue
}

val jValueArr: JValue = getJArrayValue()
val jValueString: JValue = JValue.JString("Test")
val jValueNumber: JValue = JValue.JNumber(100f)

val jArray = JValue.JArray(listOf(jValueString, jValueNumber, jValueArr))

fun getJArrayValue(): JValue.JArray = JValue.JArray(listOf(jValueArr))

fun main() {
    println(jArray.value)
}
```

The problematic parts are `JObject` and `JArray` as they can hold a `JValue` (circular dependency?)

If I run the above code it prints the below value as jArray

```
[JString(value=Test), JNumber(value=100.0), JArray(value=[null])]
```

as you see the third element is `JArray(value=[null])` instead of `jValueArr`, but I can understand that it's null because the kotlin initializes the objects lazy and `jValueArr` won't be initialized while calling `getJArrayValue()`.

**My question is, how can I properly handle this scenario?**

Link to my actual code - https://github.com/VenkateswaranJ/ParserCombinatorsKT/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/JsonParser.kt#L98-L130

**Update:**

I fixed it in my parser with some dummy forward reference (not sure it's the best way of doing it)
Here is the code - https://github.com/VenkateswaranJ/ParserCombinatorsKT/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/JsonParser.kt#L16-L26

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it is not possible to have a circular reference where both sides are read-only. We have to make at least one side mutable.

In your specific case we have a list, so we can initially create a mutable list and then make it read-only:

```kotlin
val jValueArr: JValue = run {
    val list = mutableListOf<JValue>()
    JValue.JArray(list).also { list += it }
}
```

Above solution may be considered not exactly safe, as we can cast the list back to `MutableList` and mutate it. Alternatively, we can create our own implementation of `MutableList` which doesn't allow mutating after switching it to read-only. Or we can use [buildList()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) which provides such implementation already.

Please be aware you can't print data classes with circular references, because then you get into an infinite recursion. Also, it feels strange to use circular references in a data structure which seems related to JSON. JSON doesn't support circular references.

Comment: Basically I wanna make this (F#) forward-references in kotlin but don't know how https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators-4/#forward-references

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the circular initialization problem with lazy initialization of jValueArr:

```
val jValueArr by lazy { getJArrayValue() }
```

unless you declare your variable lazy, it is initialized in the order of declaration.

Yet, you will still have a circular dependency issue, in your current design, your getJArrayValue function is creating a JArray with a list that contains jValueArr itself. This can lead to infinite recursion, as it's essentially a circular structure where jValueArr contains itself, which contains itself, and so on.

You should redesign your data to avoid endless recursion.